# Вывод данных

Tags: php

Подскажите, как отсортировать данные из БД? Если пользователь ввел информацию, то она отображалась, если нет, то нет. Если, например, он ввел phone, то вывелось phone +34532345, если нет, то поле Phone не выводилось! Что-то похожее используется здесь и в соц сетях, как эта обработка работает? Подкиньте примерчик, пожалуйста. Спасибо!

Comment: Уточните вопрос, а то совсем непонятно ;)

Comment: Я имею ввиду вывод только тех, данных которых ввел пользователь, такое есть в соц сетях, например, там где то, что пользователь ввел, то и показывается, если он ввел телефона, то поле с номером телефона показывается, если не ввел, то все скрывается.

Comment: if(empty($info)){}else{echo $info;}

Comment: А как можно правильно сделать ещё echo не только переменной, а ещё html кода перед переменной ?

Answer (score 3):

Ох, сударыня, не "прыгайте через три ступеньки"! Изучайте всё по порядку. Иначе и через год не вникните.

```
if(empty($phone)){
    echo "Пустое поле";
}
// или
if($phone == ''){
    echo "Пустое поле";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно с html-кодом, то вот, например:

```
if(!empty($phone)){
  echo "<b>Телефон: " . $phone . "</b><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну так перед выводом поля проверяйте пустое поле или нет: если поле заполнено, то выводите, если пустое, то не выводите.

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста пример такой проверки.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<html>
<form action="phone.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="phone">
<input type="submit" value="Ок">
</form>
</html>
```

phone.php

```
    <?php
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    if($phone == '')
    {
    echo "Введите номер!";
    }
else
    {
    echo "phone ".$phone;
    }
    ?>
```